# Diamond inheritance using Windows V2 Credential Providers

Tags: c++, winapi, credential-providers

Following situation:

I have a working V1 CP that implements the `IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential` interface. This dependency is necessary to have access to the `IQueryContinueWithStatus` interface, which I need.

```
class CCredential : public IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential
{
    [...]
```

`IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential` implements `ICredentialProviderCredential`.

The COM `IUknown` query method is done using this snippet:

```
IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface(__in REFIID riid, __deref_out void** ppv)
{
    static const QITAB qitOnlyCredUI[] =
    {
        QITABENT(CCredential, ICredentialProviderCredential),
        { 0 },
    };

    static const QITAB qitFull[] =
    {
        QITABENT(CCredential, ICredentialProviderCredential), // IID_ICredentialProviderCredential
        QITABENT(CCredential, IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential), // IID_IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential            
        { 0 },
    };

[...]
```

---

Now I want to migrate the provider to be a V2 CP and implement the `ICredentialProviderCredential2` interface, but stay compatible to the `IQueryContinueWithStatus` interface. Also, dropping `QITABENT(CCredential, ICredentialProviderCredential)` out is no option, because `qitOnlyCredUI` is necessary in case a CredUI is requested, which does not support `IQueryContinueWithStatus`.

```
class CCredential : public IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential,
                    public ICredentialProviderCredential2,
                    public ICredentialProviderCredentialWithFieldOptions
{
    [...]
```

`ICredentialProviderCredential2` implements `ICredentialProviderCredential`.

Implementing the COM `QueryInterface` method like:

```
IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface(__in REFIID riid, __deref_out void** ppv)
{
    static const QITAB qitOnlyCredUI[] =
    {
        QITABENT(CCredential, ICredentialProviderCredential),
        { 0 },
    };

    static const QITAB qitFull[] =
    {
        QITABENT(CCredential, ICredentialProviderCredential), // IID_ICredentialProviderCredential
        QITABENT(CCredential, ICredentialProviderCredential2), // IID_ICredentialProviderCredential2
        QITABENT(CCredential, IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential), // IID_IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential            
        QITABENT(CCredential, ICredentialProviderCredentialWithFieldOptions), //IID_ICredentialProviderCredentialWithFieldOptions
        { 0 },
    };
```

This is where the Diamond Problem starts, as `ICredentialProviderCredential2` and `IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential` both implement `ICredentialProviderCredential`.

Trying to compile certainly leads to the compiler complaining about ambiguous definitions for the `ICredentialProviderCredential` base class.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I don't follow your logic about having two QITAB lists. Are you saying a CredUI instance of your class can only implement the one interface? If so, how are you defining whether this is a CredUI instance or not?

Comment: (I should have said this in my first comment.) For what it's worth I do know the answer to your question; I just want to make sure you aren't implementing `QueryInterface()` incorrectly.

Comment: The Credential decides which list to return based on the CPUS scenario. And the Provider decides which one to instantiate, also based on the CPUS scenario. But you are right, one list would be enough, as the provider will take care of which interface to request and return. It's a relict, sometimes it made sense.

Comment: Right. Just remember that `QueryInterface()` on a given instance must always return the same values for the same inputs through its lifetime. If you change which `QITAB` a given object uses in the middle of its lifetime, you're breaking that rule. Did `QITABENTMULTI()` fix your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `QITABENTMULTI()` macro for your case. It's documented in `shlwapi.h`. I have no idea why it isn't on MSDN.

Comment: This fixes the `QueryInterface` issues. Thank you. But now I'm in the following situation: I have methods taking parameters of type `ICredentialProviderCredential`. Until now these references were passed using `this`, which now in turn still throws `ambiguous conversion 'CCredential *const' to 'ICredentialProviderCredential *'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay as the references passed may be reinterpreted as instances of their common base class `ICredentialProviderCredential` I ended up using `reinterpret_cast<ICredentialProviderCredential>(this)` wherever a reference to the `CCredential` class base is needed.